# R mice package: error in 2l.norm when there is only 1 NA

Tags: r, r-mice

After specifying the "2l.norm" method when calling mice i stumbled upon an error message for variables containing only 1 NA. I realize this is a very minor problem considering the very minor amount of missing data for these variables. However, it would be elegant to take into account the data structure for these as well.

I re-created the situation using a database accessible for all, the ChickWeight dataset.
I very much realize that the problem can also be a consequence of an error in my implementation of the procedure, so please let me know if such is the case.

```
ChickWeight[1:20, ]
dim(ChickWeight)
sum(is.na(ChickWeight)) #contains no NAs
ChickWeight$weight[12] <- NA # add 1 NA
ChickWeight$constant <- 1 #add a constant
ChickWeight$Chick <- as.numeric(levels(ChickWeight$Chick)[ChickWeight$Chick]) #class variable has to be an integer

ini <- mice(ChickWeight, maxit = 0)
pred <- ini$predictorMatrix
pred["weight", ] <- c(0, 2, -2, 1, 2)
method <- ini$method
method["weight"] <- "2l.norm"
imputation <- mice(ChickWeight, m = 5, maxit = 5, pred = pred, method = method)
```

The last command results in:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , i, value = c(37.3233463394145, 159.862324738397 : replacement has 2 rows, data has 1

Adding one extra NA solves the problem

```
ChickWeight$weight[13] <- NA # add another NA
imputation <- mice(ChickWeight, m = 5, maxit = 5, pred = pred, method = method)
```

Does anyone know what could cause the error?

Comment: In this case you could use `"2l.pan"` equally well, which doesn't produce that error. You don't need heterogenuous within-group variances with only one missing value. The two methods are equicalent otherwise. Could well be that this is even the problem... If this solves your question (I cannot provide an answer to why `"2l.norm"` won't do it), then I will post this as an answer. I don't see flaws in your procedure, although I think `mice` will add the intercept automatically, so in my view you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Simon. It has a nice logic to it which i unfortunately didn't see. Also, i think your right about the automatic addition of an intercept.
As for the final answer i'm as yet inclined to leave open for a while to allow for a small fix/adjustment in the code (if it needs any); for me personally however, it solves my problem

Comment: The logic is simply that "2l.pan" will also perform MI under a two-level model with fixed and random effects for intercept and predictors. It's basically an interface to the actual `pan` package that makes `pan` impute values in the fully conditional way (by iterating between variables; originally `pan` uses a joint model) as `mice` always does. If you really have so few missing value, then you'll be quite okay with "2l.pan". You won't "lose" much, and personally I prefer the pan model in most cases anyway.

Comment: Thanks again Simon. I meant to say i didn't see it before i read your comment, but any extra explication is always welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was kindly provided to me by email by Stef van Buuren, the author of the mice package.
There is a very minor omission in the `mice.impute.2l.norm` function in v2.22 of the mice package and has since been fixed in [v2.23](https://github.com/amices/mice/blame/master/NEWS.md#L377).

The correct code is the following, where only `drop = FALSE` was added in the 4th from last row to `rowSums(as.matrix(x[nry, type == 2]), ...`:

```r
mice.impute.2l.norm2 <- 
function (y, ry, x, type, intercept = TRUE, ...) 
{
  rwishart <- function(df, p = nrow(SqrtSigma), SqrtSigma = diag(p)) {
    Z <- matrix(0, p, p)
    diag(Z) <- sqrt(rchisq(p, df:(df - p + 1)))
    if (p > 1) {
      pseq <- 1:(p - 1)
      Z[rep(p * pseq, pseq) + unlist(lapply(pseq, seq))] <- rnorm(p * 
                                                                    (p - 1)/2)
    }
    crossprod(Z %*% SqrtSigma)
  }
  force.chol <- function(x, warn = TRUE) {
    z <- 0
    repeat {
      lambda <- 0.1 * z
      XT <- x + diag(x = lambda, nrow = nrow(x))
      XT <- (XT + t(XT))/2
      s <- try(expr = chol(XT), silent = TRUE)
      if (class(s) != "try-error") 
        break
      z <- z + 1
    }
    attr(s, "forced") <- (z > 0)
    if (warn && z > 0) 
      warning("Cholesky decomposition had to be forced", 
              call. = FALSE)
    return(s)
  }
  if (intercept) {
    x <- cbind(1, as.matrix(x))
    type <- c(2, type)
  }
  n.iter <- 100
  nry <- !ry
  n.class <- length(unique(x[, type == (-2)]))
  if (n.class == 0) 
    stop("No class variable")
  gf.full <- factor(x[, type == (-2)], labels = 1:n.class)
  gf <- gf.full[ry]
  XG <- split.data.frame(as.matrix(x[ry, type == 2]), gf)
  X.SS <- lapply(XG, crossprod)
  yg <- split(as.vector(y[ry]), gf)
  n.g <- tabulate(gf)
  n.rc <- ncol(XG[[1]])
  bees <- matrix(0, nrow = n.class, ncol = n.rc)
  ss <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = n.class)
  mu <- rep(0, n.rc)
  inv.psi <- diag(1, n.rc, n.rc)
  inv.sigma2 <- rep(1, n.class)
  sigma2.0 <- 1
  theta <- 1
  for (iter in 1:n.iter) {
    for (class in 1:n.class) {
      vv <- sym(inv.sigma2[class] * X.SS[[class]] + inv.psi)
      bees.var <- chol2inv(chol(vv))
      bees[class, ] <- drop(bees.var %*% (crossprod(inv.sigma2[class] * 
                                                      XG[[class]], yg[[class]]) + inv.psi %*% mu)) + 
        drop(rnorm(n = n.rc) %*% chol(sym(bees.var)))
      ss[class] <- crossprod(yg[[class]] - XG[[class]] %*% 
                               bees[class, ])
    }
    mu <- colMeans(bees) + drop(rnorm(n = n.rc) %*% chol(chol2inv(chol(sym(inv.psi)))/n.class))
    inv.psi <- rwishart(df = n.class - n.rc - 1, SqrtSigma = chol(chol2inv(chol(sym(crossprod(t(t(bees) - 
                                                                                                  mu)))))))
    inv.sigma2 <- rgamma(n.class, n.g/2 + 1/(2 * theta), 
                         scale = 2 * theta/(ss * theta + sigma2.0))
    H <- 1/mean(inv.sigma2)
    sigma2.0 <- rgamma(1, n.class/(2 * theta) + 1, scale = 2 * 
                         theta * H/n.class)
    G <- exp(mean(log(1/inv.sigma2)))
    theta <- 1/rgamma(1, n.class/2 - 1, scale = 2/(n.class * 
                                                     (sigma2.0/H - log(sigma2.0) + log(G) - 1)))
  }
  imps <- rnorm(n = sum(nry), sd = sqrt(1/inv.sigma2[gf.full[nry]])) + 
    rowSums(as.matrix(x[nry, type == 2, drop = FALSE]) * bees[gf.full[nry], 
                                                              ])
  return(imps)
}
```

When the new function is added to the `mice` namespace by

```r
environment(mice.impute.2l.norm2) <- asNamespace('mice')
```

it can be used as normal in mice by calling for `2l.norm2`. To show in the previously described example:

```r
method["weight"] <- "2l.norm2"
imputation <- mice(ChickWeight, m = 5, maxit = 5, pred = pred, method = method)
```

It now works as expected!